# Will the order of minify and concatenate make difference for batch of JavaScript/CSS files?

Tags: javascript, compression, concatenation

To reduce http requests and minify static files download, it is recommended to concatenate and minify all JavaScript/CSS files used by single page.

Does it make difference?

1) Minify all javascript files and then concatenate them;

2) Concatenate all javascript files and then minify them.

Comment: You need to accept more answers.  You've asked over 160 questions and have a high rep...you should know better.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I always forgot to click the accept "Check":) I'll do a batch job for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minifying several smaller files *into* one big file (through `>>` redirect, for example) appeals by the fact that good minifyers will complain if they find a syntax error in one of those files. You will immediately see *in which* file.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference what order you do them in.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.SVG` for pictures, if you cant then use `WebP`, use `WebM` for Video, but the order of static files dont make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to concatenate all javascript files before then minify them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not skip both and just compress your JavaScript?  You won't have to concatenate your code because all your files will be in one archive and you'll get a smaller file with compression than with minification.  If you're running Apache, mod-gzip will let you precompress your files to take a little load off the server.

See: http://tutorialajax.com/compress-javascript-with-gzip.html

Also: http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

Comment: gzip is no-loss compression, while minify can trim unnecessary info in JavaScript.

Comment: @Morgan, did you do any actual testing between minification and compression? I did; here are my results. I used the [Rialto JavaScript library](http://rialto.improve-technologies.com/wiki/) which comes as one big non-minified js file with a size of 553 KB. I ran it through the two minifiers at http://jscompress.com/, the file sizes came out to be 413 KB (JSMin) and 198 KB (Packer).  I also applied two compressors at default settings, gzip (used in mod_gzip): 88 KB and Deflate (used in mod_deflate): 89 KB. If you want to reduce the size of the download, then compress as I said in my answer.

Comment: I did comparison between minify and gzip. It turns out that gzip wins over minify if it is small (<5KB generally), while minify wins if it is large enough. Due to existence of anti-malware software and proxy, 10% "Accept-Encoding" headers are stripped. So, non-gzip content is served. So, the preferred way is to: minify first, then compress it.

Comment: I disagree with your findings, as I tested with a 500+ KB js file. The resulting minified file was 5x larger than the gzipped file.  If (as in Packer) the symbols are also modified the file is still > 2x larger than with gzip.

Comment: Perhaps you are right in some cases. But, does gzip after minify assure better result?

Comment: This debate is really interesting and I like the arguments both of you are exposing. Smart people are discussing!

Comment: Tests are done here: http://engineeredweb.com/blog/why-minify-javascript/ Conclusion: You -should- minify.

Comment: I know this is old but @Paul, how can you disagree with one's finding?  You can disagree with his conclusion or hypothesis on his findings, but not the actual data itself.

Comment: @evan.stoddard I disagreed because I got different results in my own tests. However, as you point out that was a long time ago. Since then I've got a lot more web-related code under my belt (both front- and back-end)...over 6 years worth in fact.  I disagree with my answer and my arguments but I'm not going to delete my answer because there's value in the comments others made.  Thanks for commenting and thus allowing me to comment on my ignorance at the time!

Comment: @Paul Understood.  Thanks your your honest reply!  :)